# calculating rolling window covariance using two equivalent(?) "other" parameters yields two different result

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4),
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000',
                                      periods=100),
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
r = df.rolling(20)
r2 = df["D"].rolling(20)

result1 = r[["A", "B", "C"]].cov(r["D"])
result2 = r[["A", "B", "C"]].cov(r2)
```

The goal is to calculate column A,B,C against D's covariance. I thought result1 and result2 should be the same, but apparently they are not. It seems to me that `r2` is equivalent of `r["d"]`. What am I missing?

Comment: Good question!  I'm not sure what is the right way here and with the new syntax (for rolling in version 0.18.0) it is less clear to me how to do the rolling covariance whereas variance, mean, etc. is fairly straightforward.  result2 seems to give the right answer so I'd go with that but I couldn't guess why result1 doesn't work, though it wouldn't be surprising that the new rolling methods still have some rough edges.